# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'LastUpdated' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I just recently upgraded our Kentico CMS to latest hotfix. After the push to the prod servers, i am getting the below error on both the servers.

Has any one else worked through this error? I think this has to do some thing with the caching but i can't pin point the issue here.

We are using

- SQL server for session state.
- both the servers are virtual machines
- both the servers are upto date - patches etc

Now kentico suggested to reinstall .net on both the servers since they are thinking this is environment related problem.

Elmah picks this error and sends it to me. The site shows just fine through this error.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'LastUpdated' was not found.
Generated: Tue, 01 Jul 2014 23:11:07 GMT

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'LastUpdated' was not found.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type)
   at CMS.SettingsProvider.BaseInfo..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, TypeInfo[] typeInfos)
   at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfo`1..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, TypeInfo[] typeInfos)
   at CMS.SiteProvider.UserInfo..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at CMS.CMSHelper.CurrentUserInfo..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name)
   at CMS.GlobalHelper.SessionHelper.GetValue(String key)
   at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.GetCurrentUser(Boolean& loadUserData, Boolean cacheResult)
   at CMS.CMSHelper.ContextData.get_CurrentUser()
   at CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.get_CurrentUser()
   at CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.SetCulture()
   at CMS.UIControls.DocumentBase.PreInit()
   at CMS.UIControls.ContentPage.OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
   at CMSPages_PortalTemplate.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) in d:\inetpub\NrccuaWeb\Cms20140701-KU\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx.cs:line 142
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.cmspages_portaltemplate_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cms\3bfbd4f3\28ac498a\App_Web_portaltemplate.aspx.67ab7734.p3gr9fmc.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Thanks.

Comment: looks like the code base and database are out of sync.  LastUpdated seems to be missing from the userInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old questions but since I just ran into this so I'll post the solution for the next person.

This can happen when you are using SQL Server to store your session state.

Kentico stores the userinfo object in the session so sometime before you upgraded you were logged into the kentico site and the userinfo object got serialized the the SQL Server session database.

After the upgrade when you accessed the site the userinfo object saved in the session database was deserialized, since that object was changed by the upgrade a serialization exception is thrown.

You can either wait for you session to expire, clear your session cookie, or if you want to avoid the problem for any user of you site, clear the ASPStateTempSessions table in your SQL Server session database.

This only doesn't happen with the default inProc session state since it is cleared by the site restart after the upgrade is complete.